# How can I list only pages that have no subcategories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently a Page can also be a Subcategory , so when I call related_subcategories on a Page it checks if the Page is a Subcategory.

How would I iterate only to show Pages that are not Subcategories?

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories,
    class_name: "Page",
    join_table: "subcategories",
    foreign_key: "page_id",
    association_foreign_key: "other_page_id"

  has_and_belongs_to_many :related_subcategories,
    class_name: "Page",
    join_table: "subcategories",
    foreign_key: "other_page_id",
    association_foreign_key: "page_id"


end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Page.joins("RIGHT JOIN subcategories ON pages.id = subcategories.other_page_id").where("subcategories.other_page_id IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a scoped query

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

Perhaps something like:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories,
    class_name: "Page",
    join_table: "subcategories",
    foreign_key: "page_id",
    association_foreign_key: "other_page_id"

  has_and_belongs_to_many :related_subcategories,
    class_name: "Page",
    join_table: "subcategories",
    foreign_key: "other_page_id",
    association_foreign_key: "page_id"

  scope :not_subcategoried, -> { where('related_subcategories_count = ?',0) }
```